# Iptables allow only localhost and gmail

Tags: iptables, localhost, gmail

I use this in iptables: (want to allow 25 port only for localhost)

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s localhost --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j DROP
```

It works perfect, but I stopped to receive forwarded mail (it was working OK before).

I have a rule in mail config -> email sent to myusername@mydomain.com -> forwarded to my gmail

What should I change/add in my iptables to allow this forwarding but port 25 to be closed for public? Maybe add google IP or something else?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If this is a standalone host, I suggest you solve this issue within your mailserver, not a firewall. Gmail has every right to change their IP addresses as they see fit at any time and you'll end up having a broken system. Configure your mailserver to accept mails to addresses you allow and possibly from addresses you allow. Alternatively use something like [fetchmail](http://fetchmail.berlios.de/) to download your mails from Gmail instead of using a forward.

Answer (score 0):

You should create iptales rule that allow only gmail ip address on port 25.

Gmail's name server ip addresses are as follows.

```
173.194.36.53 
173.194.36.54
```

It may be different in your country.
You can find using following command in terminal.

> nslookup gmail.com